# I can not figure out the answer to this greatest integer problem

Tags: factorial, pi

I can’t figure out the answer to this problem:

$$\left\lfloor\sqrt{\lfloor\pi\rfloor!}\right\rfloor=\;?$$

Comment: Did I interpret the problem correctly when I fixed the notation?

Comment: yes!  I did not know how to write it like you.

Comment: You can find out how to write mathematics here by starting on [this page](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) and following the links.

Answer (score 4):

Since $3\le\pi<4$, $\lfloor\pi\rfloor=3$, and $3!=3\cdot2\cdot1=6$, so we want $\left\lfloor\sqrt6\right\rfloor$. The square root of $6$ is between what two consecutive integers?

Comment: The square root of 6  is between what two consecutive integers? is it 2 and 3?

Comment: @sawblade: That’s right: $2^2=4<6<9=3^2$, so $2<\sqrt6<3$. Therefore $\left\lfloor\sqrt6\right\rfloor=\;$?

Comment: 3 since it is asking for the greatest integer so y=3

Comment: @sawblade: No, you want the greatest integer that is **less than or equal to** $\sqrt6$. $3$ is not $\le\sqrt6$: $3$ is **greater than** $\sqrt6$.

Comment: Ahh, now I get it.  Thank you for all of your help!

Comment: @sawblade: You’re very welcome!